# Synchronization from iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I'm trying to prove how information storage works in iCloud. I'm starting with the Userdefaults. I do something simple, a table, I add a text I keep it in an array in the Userdefaults and I synchronize it with the cloud. If I put it on 2 devices, when I start the second device (with the same iCloud user) it is updated with the data I put in the first one. But if I add another element, it is saved in the cloud, but no notification comes to the second device to update it. If I close the second and reopen it, it picks up the changes. I have tried to put the notification in both the AppDelegate and directly in the controller with the same result. 
Class that I use for the Userdefaults:

```
class UserDef: NSObject {
let def = UserDefaults.standard
let store = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()
static var kName = "nombre"
static var kArray = "array"

var delegate: ViewController?

public func setArray(arr:[String], update: Bool = true) {
    def.set(arr, forKey: UserDef.kArray)
    if update == true {
        //guardo en la nube
        store.set(arr, forKey: UserDef.kArray)
        store.synchronize()
    }
}

public func getArray() -> [String] {
    if let a = def.object(forKey: UserDef.kArray) as? [String] {
        return a
    } else {
        return []
    }
}

public func newCloudArray(array: [String]) {
//me pasan el array del cloud
    self.setArray(arr: array, update: false)   
    self.delegate?.reload()
}
}
```

In the Appdelegate I put this and it is collected at the beginning:

```
var store = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ubiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChange), name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification, object: store)
    store.synchronize()
    return true
}

@objc public func ubiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let a = store.array(forKey: "array") as! [String]
    UserDef().newCloudArray(array: a)

}
```

I understand that if from another device I update iCloud, I should get the notification didChangeExternallyNotification and from there collect the data and update the Userdefaults, but I receive nothing.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The iCloud Key-Value Data storage offers only **eventual consistency**.
Thus changes in one Device will eventually show up on another device at some time in the future. Thus it's recommended from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html)

> To avoid using key-value storage for data essential to your app’s
>   behavior when offline; instead, store such data directly into the
>   local user defaults database.

[image: iCloud Key-Value]